# To use the correct test for independence

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, independence, error-message

I have 2 groups (data.frame) in R called `good` and `bad` which contains good users and bad users respectively.

The group `good` contains `game_id` which is the id for a computergame and `number` which is how many times this game has been played.

For example `good$game_id` we get `1 2 3 ... 20`. We have 20 games.
Similar `good$number` we get `45214 1254 23 ... 8914` which is the number the game has been played. For example has `game_id==1` been played 45214 times in group `good`.

Similar for `bad`.
We also have the same number of users in the two groups.

For

```
head(good)
```

we get

`game_id  number`

```
1   45214
2   1254
...
20  8914
```

I want to investigate if there is dependence between the number of times a fixed computergame has been played.

For `game_id==1` I would try to use Pearson's Chi test for 'Independence'. 
In R I type `chisq.test(good[1,2], bad[1,2])` to see if there is indepence between `good` and `bad` for `game_id==1` but I get an error message: `x and y must have same levels.`

How can this problem be solved ?

Comment: Can you post the result of `head(your_data.frame)`?

Comment: The error message suggests that you are feeding the function with factors instead of numbers/counts. `str(good)` and `str(bad)` will tell if that is so. If yes, this part of the question is about R programming and not on topic for this forum. In that case you should go back to how the data entered R and what went wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a game has been played 1554 times and you wonder what share of these uses happened by a `good` and how many by a `bad`. This can be done via a binomial test. Let's say we observed the game being played by `good` 1254 times and by `bad` 300 times. `binom.test` says

```
> binom.test(c(1254, 300))

    Exact binomial test

data:  c(1254, 300)
number of successes = 1254, number of trials = 1554, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7864318 0.8263009
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.8069498
```

So the confidence interval for the true share of `good` players is 78% to 82% and we reject the null hypothesis of each kind of player being equally likely.

Now for your strange data format (corresponding data should really be in one dataframe) it is probably adviseable that you make a reproducible example. This seems to work:

```
good <- data.frame(game_id = 1:3,
                  number = sample(3000:5000, 3))
bad  <- data.frame(game_id = 1:3,
                  number = sample(300:500, 3))
for(i in 1:3){
    print(i)
    print(c(good[i, "number"], bad[i, "number"]))
    print(binom.test(x = c(good[i, "number"], bad[i, "number"])))
}
```

Better programming style yet: Merge `good` and `bad` into a common dataframe first:

```
good <- data.frame(game_id = 1:3,
                  number = sample(3000:5000, 3))
bad  <- data.frame(game_id = 1:3,
                  number = sample(300:500, 3))

common <- merge(good, bad, by = "game_id")

apply(common, MARGIN = 1, function(line) binom.test(line[2:3]))
```